# What is the practice to follow when need to expose a WinAPI enumeration?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, enums, pinvoke

I would like to know which is the proper practice to follow when need to expose a WinAPI enumeration.

( I think this question affects both C# and VB.Net because just its a member visibility question )

I have a `NativeMethods` Class as indicates **MSDN** to follow best practices when P/Invoking, well, inside my `NativeMethods` I have declared the `SetSystemCursor` function from Windows API, and also the required **Enum** for `id` parameter of `SetSystemCursor` function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648395%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Then, I did a little wrapper:

```vb
Public Shared Function SetSystemCursor(ByVal filePath As String,
                                       ByVal cursorType As NativeMethods.SystemCursorId) As Boolean

    Return NativeMethods.SetSystemCursor(NativeMethods.LoadCursorFromFile(filePath), cursorType)

End Function
```

Note the `cursorType` parameter, the problem is that `SystemCursorId` **Enum** is not public because as I said is part of the platform invoking definitions inside the `NativeMethods` class, so, to be able use the wrapper I could do two things, first make public the `SystemCursorId` **Enum** ...this means move the **Enum** outside the private `NativeMethods` Class like this:

```vb
Public Class MyClass

    Private Class NativeMethods

    ' ...

    End Class

    Public Enum SystemCursorId

        Arrow = 32512

        Crosshair = 32515

    End Enum

End Class
```

Or secondly, re-declare the same **Enum** outside the `NativeMethods` class to expose it, something like this:

```vb
Public Class MyClass

    Private Class NativeMethods

        Friend Enum SystemCursorId

            Arrow = 32512

            Crosshair = 32515

        End Enum

    End Class

    Public Enum SystemCursorId

        Arrow = NativeMethods.SystemCursorId.Arrow

        Crosshair = NativeMethods.SystemCursorId.Crosshair

    End Enum

End Class
```

So, in this circunstances, which is the recommended programming practice to follow?.

Comment: I think this is a matter of opinion. If the .NET API is a straightforward implementation of the native API, then just expose the enums as-is. In general (specifically because you can pass *anything* as an `enum`), I think it's best to validate the .NET args, and translate them to the native API args. In other words, two different `enum`s.  This helps to decouple the .NET API from the native.

Comment: +1 for @JonathonReinhart.  Look at the `enum`s required for working with files: `FileMode` directly corresponds to the `dwFileDisposition` constants, `FileShare` is basically those constants, but some are added, and `FileAccess` is entirely translated since none of the values match.